# local trivialisation of $G$-torsor

Tags: general-topology

Let $G$ be a group, $X$ a topological space and a $G$-set where $x \mapsto g.x$ is a continuous map for every $g \in G$. (We consider $G$ as a topological space with the discrete topology).

Let $S$ be a topological space with the trivial $G$-action. A $G$-torsor over $S$ is a $G$-set $X$ with a $G$-equivariant surjective local homeomorphism $p: X \to S$ such that the map
$$G \times X \to X \times_S X, (g,x) \mapsto (g.x,x)$$
is a homeomorphism.

How do I show that a $G$-torsor is locally trivial: there exists an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $S$ and a $G$-equivariant homeomorphism $p^{-1}(U_i) \to G \times U_i$.
And also $X/G \simeq S$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following composition:
$$
\varphi\colon X \times_S X \to G\times X \to G 
$$
where the first map is the inverse of the action map, and the second one is the projection onto $G$. Observe, that it satisfies the following property
$$
\varphi(x,x') \cdot x = x' 
$$
Consider $s_0\in S$ and $U\subseteq S$ and open set containing $s_0$ so that it admits a local section of $p$ (this exists because $p$ is a local homeomorphism). Namely, there exists $\sigma\colon U\subseteq S \to X$ a local section of $p$. Then, the map 
$$
U\times G \to p^{-1}(U)
$$
defined by the rule $(s,g) \to (g\cdot \sigma(s))$ is a homeomorphism with inverse $x \to (p(x), \varphi(x,\sigma \circ p (x)))$.